# Easiest and fastest way to encrypt/decrypt in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm sending a value to the client that I want encrypted (and decrypted if/when received back).

It is not super sensitive data, I just don't want to send it in plain naked text.

I know of [ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html) but it seemingly requires too many steps for my basic need. Perhaps I'm overthinking it and there's no heavy computation involved under the hood but I'm intuitively looking for something more like how setting/reading a signed cookie works.

It would be a great advantage if I wouldn't need to include anything more than what comes out of the box with Rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not put it in the session? Then it will be part of the encrypted cookie / in your session store.

You can set the value with `session[:message] = "my message"` and get it with `session[:message]`.

Comment: I'm setting the value in a data attribute that then in turn is picked up by javascript and sent back to the server. I find it less complicated to read from a data attribute than from a cookie.

Comment: Yeah but if your javascript needs it, you can't really encrypt it. Right?

Comment: Javscript will not use it more than passing the encrypted string back to the server.

Comment: Right, but the request comes with a session! Haha thats what the session is for, to hold onto values like that

Answer (score 1):

Using Cipher which comes included in ruby @ OpenSSL seems simple.
Try this on irb:

```
require "openssl"
data = "Very, very confidential data"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
cipher.encrypt
key = cipher.random_key
iv = cipher.random_iv

encrypted = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = key
decipher.iv = iv

plain = decipher.update(encrypted) + decipher.final
puts data == plain
```